# connect to wifi WPA2-Enterprise using wifi dongle

Tags: wifi

I want to using wifi dongle Wireless-N (802.11n) USB 2.0 on my raspberry pi 4. But it seems cant connect to wifi with WPA2-enterprise type. is there any solution to connect WPA2-Enterprise with wifi dongle?

Thanks

Comment: there's plenty of help if you search for "raspberry pi wpa2 enterprise" ... of course, it may depend on the exact nature of the "dongle" - is the dongle usable at all?

Comment: search `linux wifi dongle WPA2-Enterprise`